# Project is not built

Tags: android

Information:Gradle tasks [:aFileDialog:generateDebugSources, :aFileDialog:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :aFileDialog:mockableAndroidJar, :aFileDialog:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :core:generateDebugSources, :core:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :core:mockableAndroidJar, :core:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :zxing:generateDebugSources, :zxing:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :zxing:mockableAndroidJar, :zxing:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
C:\Users\zainm\Desktop\latest\newlatest\kalikoe-wallet\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v26\values-v26.xml
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use facebook sdk, try this in gradle.

```
compile ("com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)"){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
```

Or search the dependency using V26.